# Is there any way to get dynamic created connection between nodes of VIS.js

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I am creating a page on which, I have already placed all the nodes using vis.js. Here user is free to create edges between the nodes.
My question is that how can I get json of the network which contains node information with egde connection.

[image]

According to above screen i have created this UI, Now user can add edge dynamically.
I want the json of this network to save into db.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link given by vis.js [save and load](http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/saveAndLoad.html)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Please try to include a minimal code example, you can take it from the source of the linked page you've provided. This is very useful for users of SO in case the linked site is taken offline.